# Game Maker Networking Issue on Port Bind

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-1.4

I want to create a simple server using GameMaker 1.4. But it's function never works on the first try, no idea why..

```
var networkType = network_socket_tcp;
var port = 50000;
var maxClients = 32;
var bufferSize = 1024;
var bufferType = buffer_fixed;
var bufferAlign = 1;

server = network_create_server(networkType, port, maxClients);

global.buffer = buffer_create(bufferSize,bufferType,bufferAlign);
sockets = ds_list_create();

if server s_msg("Server is up! Port: " + string(port));
else s_msg("Server is down!");
```

The message will be "Server down". No matter the port neither the net type.
When I try the same code with a loop, it works on the second try.
Like this:

```
var networkType = network_socket_tcp;
var port = 50000;
var maxClients = 32;
var bufferSize = 1024;
var bufferType = buffer_fixed;
var bufferAlign = 1;

server = network_create_server(networkType, port, maxClients);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

while (!server && port < 65535){
   port++;
   server = network_create_server(networkType, port, maxClients);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

global.buffer = buffer_create(bufferSize,bufferType,bufferAlign);
sockets = ds_list_create();

if server s_msg("Server is up! Port: " + string(port));
else s_msg("Server is down!");
```

Here the message will result on "Server up! Port: 50001".
As I said, no matter the port.. it could be set to 50001 at the beginning resulting on create the server to 50002.
Could someone point my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION (From user Humayun in GM Forums): network_create_server returns an index from 0, so it can't be checked as false/true since the first index would be 0 which returns false. Explains that on the second try i was creating a second instance to the sever variable indexed as 1, and so returning true.